# как реализовать сортировку кучей?

Tags: ассемблер, emu8086

помогите реализовать сортировку кучей на языке ассемблера

эмулятор emu8086

я начал код, но больше в голову ничего не приходит, надеюсь на помощь, и если можно с комментариями кода, чтобы я мог разобраться в нем

мой код

````
ORG 100h

    lea si,ar
    mov j,0
p2:
    inc j
    cmp j,size
    je qw

     mov lg, ar[j]
     mov l, ar[2*si+1]
     mov r, ar[2*si+2]
     cmp l, lg
     jg c11
     cmp r,lg
    jg c12

    cmp lg,ar[si]
    jne c13
c11:    
    mov lg,l


c12:
    mov lg,r


c13:
    mov ar[0], ar [si]
    jmp p2


qw:


ret
size dw 7
l dw 0
lg dw 0
r dw 0
ar dw 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

j dw 0
DEFINE_scan_num
DEFINE_print_num
DEFINE_print_num_uns
DEFINE_pthis
define_clear_screen```
````